# flatten nested tuple in scala (without shapeless)

Tags: scala, generics, type-safety

I'm writing a decoder to parse from byte stream to object with predefined format. I came up with below class

```
trait Decoder[In] {
  type Out
  def decode(bs: In): (Out, In)
}

object Decoder {
  type ByteString = List[Byte] // for testing...

  // define some blocks for client to chain up to build format pattern
  val int = new Decoder[ByteString] {
    type Out = Int
    def decode(bs: ByteString): (Out, ByteString) = {
      val (fst, snd) = bs.splitAt(4)
      val value = fst.foldLeft(0)((acc, b) => acc * 0xff + b)
      (value, snd)
    }
  }
  val long = new Decoder[ByteString] {
    type Out = Long
    def decode(bs: ByteString): (Out, ByteString) = {
      val (fst, snd) = bs.splitAt(8)
      val value = fst.foldLeft(0L)((acc, b) => acc * 0xff + b)
      (value, snd)
    }
  }
}
```

then created a helper builder to chain block together:

```
class DecoderBuilder[In](decoder: Decoder[In]) {
  def ~(d: Decoder[In]) = {
    val combine = new Decoder[In] {
      type Out = (decoder.Out, d.Out)
      def decode(bs: In): (Out, In) = {
        val (el1, remain1) = decoder.decode(bs)
        val (el2, remain2) = d.decode(remain1)
        ((el1, el2), remain2)
      }
    }
    new DecoderBuilder(combine)
  }

  def buildApply[T](data: In)(f: decoder.Out => T) = f(decoder.decode(data)._1)
}
object DecoderBuilder {
  implicit def ddd[In](d: Decoder[In]) = new DecoderBuilder(d)
}
```

With above code I can already write some code like this:

```
import Decoder._
import DecoderBuilder._

  val data = List[Byte](
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, // the 1st field: Int
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, // 2nd field: Long
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03 // the 3rt field: Int
    )
  val format_type = int ~ long ~ int
  val result_type = format_type.buildApply(data) {
    case ((i, l), ii) => MyObject(i, l, ii)
  }
  println(result_type) // --> MyObject(1,2,3)
```

However, when the format pattern become longer, the nested tuple become harder to read. Is there anyway to rewrite above `DecoderBuilder` so that the client side (with `buildApply`) can use flattened tuple instead? I know that shapeless can easily do this but I don't want to add an extra library just for this.

p/s:
Now looking carefully at the code again, I realized that it can not infer the type inside `buildApply`, i.e I can not do this

```
val result_type = format_type.buildApply(data) {
  a => MyObject(a._1._1, a._1._2, a.2)
}
```

because type of `a` is `format_typedecoder.Out`, not `((Int, Long), Int).

What should I do to allow that?

Answer (score 3):

shapeless is published under a permissive licence, Apache 2.0, there's nothing to prevent you from simply copying and pasting the relevant type classes and instances into your project. You won't do much better, and you're very welcome to do just that.

Comment: I've realized that we can fold through HList, so amazing! So I think I will encode the format like `int::long::int::HNil` then fold over it, using another HList as a accumulator to get back `1::2::3::HNil`. But looking at the fold example on shapeless repo, I'm still don't know how to do that, or if it is possible at all. Could you please give me some hint? And again thank you for such helpful library :)